# Replace NULL value in nested tibble / dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, nested, tidyr, tibble

I have this tibble of tibbles:

```r
a = tibble(a = c(1:3))
df <- tibble::tibble(a1 = list(a,a), a2 = list(NULL,a))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  a1               a2              
  <list>           <list>          
1 <tibble [3 x 1]> <NULL>          
2 <tibble [3 x 1]> <tibble [3 x 1]>
```

I'd like to replace the `<NULL>` value with another tibble, let's say `a`.

But,

```r
df %>% tidyr::replace_na(list(a2 = a))
```

Gives this

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  a1               a2              
  <list>           <list>          
1 <tibble [3 x 1]> <int [3]>       
2 <tibble [3 x 1]> <tibble [3 x 1]>
```

While I'd like this

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  a1               a2              
  <list>           <list>          
1 <tibble [3 x 1]> <tibble [3 x 1]>   
2 <tibble [3 x 1]> <tibble [3 x 1]>
```

Is there an easy workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

a = tibble(a = c(1:3))
df <- tibble::tibble(a1 = list(a,a), a2 = list(NULL,a))

df %>% 
  replace_na(list(a2 = list(a)))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   a1               a2              
#>   <list>           <list>          
#> 1 <tibble [3 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 1]>
#> 2 <tibble [3 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 1]>
```

Comment: That was too many lists for me, I got lost, thanks!

Comment: True! You are welcome, @Maël!

Answer (score 1):

```
a <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:3)
df <- tibble::tibble(a1 = list(a, a), a2 = list(NA, a))
df[is.na(df)] <- list(a)
df
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   a1               a2              
#   <list>           <list>          
# 1 <tibble [3 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 1]>
# 2 <tibble [3 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 1]>
```

**Update as the OP modified the question:**

```
library(dplyr)

a <- tibble(a = 1:3)
df <- tibble(a1 = list(a, a), a2 = list(NULL, a))
df %>% replace(. == "NULL", list(a))
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   a1               a2              
#   <list>           <list>          
# 1 <tibble [3 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 1]>
# 2 <tibble [3 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 1]>
```

Comment: I slightly edited the question, with `df <- tibble::tibble(a1 = list(a, a), a2 = list(NULL, a))`.

Answer (score 1):

Another (general) solution, given that the level of nesting is known in advance:

```
library(purrr)

map_depth(df, .depth = 2, .f = ~if(is.null(.x)) a else .x) %>% 
  as_tibble()

#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   a1               a2              
#>   <list>           <list>          
#> 1 <tibble [3 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 1]>
#> 2 <tibble [3 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 1]>
```

For arbitrary levels of nesting, we can also use `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-pacakge:

```
library(rrapply)

rrapply(df, condition = is.null, f = function(x) a)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   a1               a2              
#>   <list>           <list>          
#> 1 <tibble [3 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 1]>
#> 2 <tibble [3 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 1]>
```